# Finding explicit forms of two polarization vectors of massless spin-1 particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

I have trouble with solving Problem 8.5 (c) from Schwartz QFT book. The problem is about finding explicit forms for the two polarizations, which are orthogonal to the momentum vector $p^\mu$ and an arbitrary reference vector $r^\mu$. My question is, is there any 'fine' way to generally express the polarization vectors using $r^\mu$ and $p^\mu$?

The reason why I used the word 'fine' is that I actually got the answer already through calculating the null space of the given matrix:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_0 & -p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3\\
r_0 & -r_1 & -r_2 & -r_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
which is.. pretty dirty. So I want to know better way to express them.

I kinda feel like it is not a "physics" question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I can set a parameter vector $t$ as
$$\epsilon_i = \varepsilon_{ijkl}p^jr^kt^l$$
so that the 4-dimensional outer product can work for two vectors. I was not sure about using this method because I need the $t$ to not be included in the spanning of $p$ and $r$, but I recently figured out that it really doesn't matter.